# How to align div tags in mobile version of site?

Tags: css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap

I'm doing a site using JSBin.

It's at http://jsbin.com/alajih/10

The issue is the mobile size I'm doing. The first image stacks fine. The second image does a weird thing where it juts to the right and isn't aligned to with the top image. Not sure why that's happening.

Here's some of the code:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .contacttext {
        font-size: 19px;
        font-weight: bold;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
    .nav {
        margin: 0;
    }

    .contact > li {
        display:block;
        width:767px;
        float:none;
    }

    .social{
        color: #fff;
        display:block;
        float:none;
    }
    li {
        padding: 7px 20px 0 0px;
    }
    row-fluid > .span8 {
        width:100%;
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }
    .span4 {
        width:100%;
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }

    .row-fluid [class*="span"] {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .row-fluid > .firstpic {
        padding: 0 0 20px 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the css adding:

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"] {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```